# Dynamically mapping columns from source to destination

Tags: ssis

I am creating an SSIS package which has a flat file source and a destination database.
The mappings between the columns are based on the following:

There is a table which contains records indicating the mappings ie: source column name and destination column name. The tables will be based on the name of the flat file.

The reason this has been done is so that the destination column names can be changed in the database rather than needing to recreate or edit the package.

Please could you advise as to how I could do this "lookup" and create the mappings dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create mappings dynamically. You'll need to either generate SSIS package programmatically on the fly, or use other method (openrowset, bcp, bulk insert...).

Comment: I have been working through creating the package programmatically as well. I created a dataflow component containing a flat file source and a oledb destination. However when I get to the point of creating the mappings between these files, I cannot access the oledb's columns to map to.